# Is there something like an interface to declare function naming only, without parameters and/or return types?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm only just starting with interfaces and I am wondering if there is a concept to handle a situation I've come across where I'd like to implement a common interface with functions that return the type of the class that implemented the interface.

Is there such a feature, or conceptual way to achieve this? Without passing in the type with every call?

Something conceptually along the lines of...

```
Interface IFoo

    Function GiveMeSomething(of T)() As T

End Interface

Public Class MyFoo
    Implements IFoo

    Public Function GiveMeANewFoo(Of T)() As T Implements IFoo.GiveMeSomething
        return new T
    End Function

End Class
```

And then usage....

```
Dim oldFoo as new MyFoo()
Dim newFoo As MyFoo = oldFoo.GiveMeANewFoo()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [generic type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx).

```
Public Interface IFoo(Of T)

    Function GiveMeSomething() As T

End Interface

Public Class Foo
    Implements IFoo(Of Foo)

    Public Function GiveMeANewFoo() As Foo Implements IFoo(Of Foo).GiveMeSomething
        Return New Foo()
    End Function

End Class
```

```
Dim oldFoo As New Foo()
Dim newFoo As Foo = oldFoo.GiveMeANewFoo()
```

Another commonly used design pattern is to let the generic interface inherit a "base interface".

```
Public Interface IFoo

    Function GiveMeSomething() As Object

End Interface

Public Interface IFoo(Of T)
    Inherits IFoo

    Overloads Function GiveMeSomething() As T

End Interface

Public Class Foo
    Implements IFoo(Of Foo)

    Public Function GiveMeANewFoo() As Foo Implements IFoo(Of Foo).GiveMeSomething
        Return New Foo()
    End Function

    Private Function GiveMeANewFooInternal() As Object Implements IFoo.GiveMeSomething
        Return Me.GiveMeANewFoo()
    End Function

End Class
```

```
Dim oldFoo As Foo = New Foo()
Dim newFoo As Foo = oldFoo.GiveMeANewFoo() 
'                   IFoo(Of Foo).GiveMeSomething | Foo.GiveMeANewFoo
```

```
Dim oldFoo As IFoo(Of Foo) = New Foo()
Dim newFoo As Foo = oldFoo.GiveMeSomething() 
'                   IFoo(Of Foo).GiveMeSomething | Foo.GiveMeANewFoo
```

```
Dim oldFoo As IFoo = New Foo()
Dim newFoo As Object = oldFoo.GiveMeSomething() 
'                      IFoo.GiveMeSomething | Foo.GiveMeANewFooInternal
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I need :)